# Bytecode interpreter in Perl

Tags: perl

Background: Need implement a parser/interpreter for some "special language syntax". My idea is, doing it in two phases:

- parse and compile the language into an intermediate code (bytecode)
- interpret the bytecode

For me is "doable" to write an parser (e.g. with RecDescent or Pegex or such), but i'm probably unable to write the bytecode interpreter part.

So, looking for something what is already done, and reduce my work only to 1st part - compile the language to the bytecode for en existing(?) interpreter (what is already written in pure perl or with XS).

Needed features:

- typeless variables
- lists
- allows usual programming constructions, like  cycles, conditions
- function definitions/calls
- execuded in the sandbox in secure way - mean:

  - **no** system calls
  - **no** I/O functions (filesystem access or such)
  - **no** direct perl-function calls
  - the **only** interraction with the *outside world* is only via perl subs what are explicitly allowed.

In short, looking for some "cripled-down" sandboxed bytecode interpreter written in perl.

Checked CPAN and found only modules what diretly compiles into "perl bytecode" what is of course insecure for my needs.

Know anybody such bytecode-interpreter perl module?